# Are matlab 2012b's classes backwards-compatible?

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I just discovered that Matlab has implemented classes, but I can't find any information as to how long this feature has existed.  Does anybody know if the classes defined by `classdef` are backwards compatible with older versions of matlab?

If so, how far back?

Comment: Looks like at least as far back as 2008a: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-in-matlab.html

Comment: @Dan, Great, thanks!  Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Yup found the same in http://wikis.controltheorypro.com/index.php?title=MATLAB_2009a_Class_Definition Apparently since 2008a they made it much easier "The new objects in MATLAB 2008a and beyond are much simpler to create and can be built, easily, in one file."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it started in 2008a:

http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-in-matlab.html

and also

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/matlabTutorial/html/objectOriented.html

Comment: @blz: note that there were some bugs in R2008a that were fixed in the following release; I tell my collaborators to install at least 2008b.